# Should a class be an attribute for another class if all I need is the data from it?

Tags: design, coding-style, class-design

Title sucks, I know, but I'm having trouble describing my question.

Say I have a class `Three_Eyed_Robot` that sees the world in RGB through three eyes. Lets call them `Red_Eye`, `Green_Eye`, `Blue_Eye`, each of which are classes of their own that load a deep learning model for vision, then store the data they see.

My question is this: should I merely have a class attribute for `Three_Eyed_Robot` called `red_data` and instantiate the `Red_Eye` class in a method that sets `red_data`, or instead have `Red_Eye` be an attribute of `Three_Eye_Robot` and use the data by calling `Three_Eyed_Robot.Red_Eye.red_data`?

Edit: clearer wording.

Comment: Depends if `Three_Eyed_Robot` ever combine the colors and exposes something more useful, or is simply a facade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Design (at least in OO) always depends on *behavior*.

So it depends on what the `Three_Eyed_Robot` *does*. I.e. what methods it has and what it needs to fulfill those methods. If it only needs the "data", then yes, it should only have the data.

In general, you should try to avoid getting data from other objects. It makes the design less maintainable, since things get used elsewhere makes seeing what happens harder.

Comment: I see what you are saying. ```Three_Eyed_Robot``` really only needs the output from the eyes, so maybe the eyes should be instantiated in methods that output the data and deleted at the end of them to keep things tidy.